# How to Resize an Image in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

it looks for a photo in base 64 format in a link and plays it, but the problem is that the photo is too big and does not fit into the page window, how can I reduce this photo and put it in the middle ??? Here is my variant but it does not work. I would appreciate your help

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  var host = 'myURL';
  var res  = '/getPhoto?id_document=';
  var id_doc = '1111');
fetch(host+res+id_doc)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    var ele = document.createElement("span");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/png;base64,"+data.snapshot);
    ele.appendChild(img);
    var elem=document.getElementById('snapshot').appendChild(ele);
})
.catch(err => console.error(err));
});
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="snapshot">
    <img id="snapshot" alt="Image" style="width: 500px">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

dont work this :

```html
  <img id="snapshot" alt="Image" style="width: 500px">
```

Comment: Offtopic, You have two the same id's, they should be unique

Comment: @LinkinTED I tried to do something like this <div id = "IMG">, then the IDs would be unique, but that didn't work.

Comment: Like said, it is offtopic, so has nothing to do with your problem, just is invalid code. You are looking for something like this: `<div style="text-align: center"><img id="snapshot" style="max-width: 80%;" /></div>`

Comment: @LinkinTED It was centered, but the photo didn't decrease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `style="width: 500px"` Won't be applied to your image, because you are creating a new element. You can define a class on css, for instance:

```
.myimage { width: 500px }
```

And apply this class to the inserted element:

```
img.classList.add("myimage")
```

Comment: Thanks, and you can show me in my example, because I'm not very clear) I'll be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML width and height tags.
Example:

```
<img id="snapshot" alt="Image" height="100px" width="100px">
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I might try is max-width instead of width, and adding 'auto' margin to left and right if you are trying to get the image centered as well.

```
.snapshot {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

`<img id="snapshot" alt="Image" class="snapshot">`